# Can i manage and keep track of my app release from one platform

Tags: android, ios, hybrid-mobile-app

Is there a common console platform, from where i can check and keep track of my app downloads from different stores and manage the builds and release from a central dashboard?

Comment: You mean different platforms (android as well as ios) in a single console ?

Comment: Yes, I mean these 2 mainly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Previously we had HockeyApp which does few things as per the question, now its being merged with 
**Visual Studio App Center** with lot more added features.

Here are some useful links in which this is explained.

https://appcenter.ms/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/stores/

https://hockeyapp.net/blog/